# How to get a image in my JS project directly?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, firefox-addon

I want to develop a extension for firefox. Now I add a image in my project, and I want to use it in my js.because my element is created dynamic,so I didn't get it from xul file. How to get the Image in JS directly?

Comment: where are you displaying the image? In a XUL context, or appended to a window?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data: URI. Here's an online generator: http://www.scalora.org/projects/uriencoder/

Answer (score 0):

If your image is in the extension package, for example in yourExtension/chrome/skin, you can access it by chrome URL, like this:

```
var yourImage = new Image(); 
yourImage.src = "chrome://yourExtension/skin/yourImage.png"; 
//do something with yourImage
```

Comment: I add this in my js file ,but it didn't work ,why? In my css file , I add the same path , it can work!